# Provision role definition permission "Override List Behaviors"

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, pnp, custom-permission-level

Situation: using PnP Provisioning Schema for site structure (lists, CTs, fields, etc). Created new permission level and want to enable specific permission "Overrdide List Behaviors" via code.
[image]

Problem: this permission is NOT defined in SPBasePermissions enumerator.. therefore I can not reference to it via code.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-services/ms412690(v=office.12)

Question : is this permission level "just not implemented in SPBasePermissions enumerator yet" or I have missed something? How to provision this permission in my custom permission level (role definition)?